# Input string was not in a correct format from numeric input

Tags: c#, winforms

I have created an application where what I type for **Product Code** is based on the database.

But I have a problem where when **Product Code** in the database does not match with what I type. It gives me the error:

`Input string was not in a correct format`

And it is pointed in:

```
price = Convert.ToDecimal(this.numericTextBox2.Text);
```

Let's say I have this data like this in database:

```
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| Product Code | Description | Sub Total |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
| SM0001       | Test        |     50000 |
+--------------+-------------+-----------+
```

When I tried in the program and I type "SM0002" in **Product Code**, the error was shown.

**Note: When Itype "Product Code" in the program, it display all the information that belong to that "Product Code" in the program**

Here is the necessary code:

```
private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdatePrice(sender, e);
}

private void UpdatePrice(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal quantity = 0;
    decimal price = 0;
    int total = 0;

    if (numericTextBox1.TextLength == 6)
    {
        this.numericUpDown1.Enabled = true;

        quantity = Convert.ToInt32(this.numericUpDown1.Value);
        price = Convert.ToDecimal(this.numericTextBox2.Text);
        total = Convert.ToInt32(quantity * price);

        if (numericUpDown1.Value > 0)
        {
            this.numericTextBox3.Text = total.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Anyone know how to solve this?

NumericTextBox1 is the textbox where into which I put **Product Code**.

In my code above, the program show the `price` and the rest based on database when the `Product Code` is hit 6 letters. But, when the program can't found what the `price` is based on the `Product Code`, it gave the error. When the `Product Code` hit 6 letters, the program will check whether the `product code` that has been entered is match with the database, if match, the program will show all information based on the entered `product code`.

**EDITED**:

The program still recognized that there is `price` that has to display whenever the entered `product code` (numericTextBox1.Text) is equal to 6. When i enter the `SM0001` it didn't show the error, because there is `price` in that `SM0001`. But when i try to put `SM0002` which is don't have the data in the database, but the `numericTextBox1.Text` is equal to 6, the program forced to display a `price` which is don't have the `price` belong to that entered `product code` (SM0002)..

What i want is when the `numericTextBox1.Text` is equal to 6 letter, it look on the information at the database, if there was a `product code` that same with the database (match), the program will display the rest of the information belong to that code <-- this is done and solved..

When i put `SM0002` which is don't have the data in the database, it gave the error.

**numericTextBox2 will come out whenever the numericTextBox1 hit 6 letters.. When the numericTextBox1 match with the database, it will display all the information. Now, my problem is when the numericTextBox1 is not match with the database, it gave the error**

Comment: Why would you think that `SM0002` is a "number"?

Comment: no, i put the ProductCode as a text, not as a number

Comment: What did you put in `numericTextBox2.Text`?

Comment: `numericTextBox2.Text` is where the `SubTotal` come out, the `SubTotal` and the rest only come out when the `Product Code` is equal to `6` letter or based on database. But, this time, i want to make the program not shown error when i type a `Product Code` that is not in the database. How do i do that?

Comment: if you will use calculator, you cannot multiply a number to a digit with letter, just think of that, so your input in your textbox2 should be numeric only.

Comment: @odlanyer: but i already convert it to decimal sir

Comment: what is the output of letter SM? When you convert it to decimal? Just think of that? Try to do it manually. To get what is the result.

Comment: You can put a breakpoint at the line `price = Convert.ToDecimal(this.numericTextBox2.Text);` and check what's the value of `this.numericTextBox2.Text`.

Comment: @odlanyer, I think the OP put 'SM0002' in numericTextBox1, but some other value in numericTextBox2.

Comment: You need to show us where you're putting something into numericTextBox2. I'd further suggest that you might want to consider using a real datamodel that stores the various data in more useful forms, and only update the user interface when you're darn good and ready... that way you'd be writing to this text field that probably shouldn't be editable, rather than reading from it and backconverting to database values....

Answer (score 0):

It must be in the line

```
price = Convert.ToDecimal(this.numericTextBox2.Text);
```

Check what you enter into `numericTextBox2`.

**EDIT**

You can try this code to detect if you have a valid number:

```
if (Decimal.TryParse(this.numericTextBox2.Text, out price))
{
     total = Convert.ToInt32(quantity * price);
}
```

Comment: `numericTextBox2.Text` is where the `SubTota`l come out, the `SubTotal` and the rest only come out when the `Product Cod`e is equal to 6 letter or based on database. But, this time, i want to make the program not shown error when i type a `Product Code` that is not in the database. How do i do that?

Comment: How do you populate `numericTextBox2`?

Comment: Check my edit, maybe that will help though I still don't really get the requirements.

Comment: `numericTextBox2` will come out whenever the `numericTextBox1` hit 6 letters.. When the `numericTextBox1` match with the database, it will display all the information. Now, my problem is when the `numericTextBox1` is not match with the database, it gave the error